# how to pull data from many to many relationship table in django orm

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many

I am trying to list all permission_id  by joining  auth_user (primary table) with auth_user_user_permissions(manyTomany ) . I tried following

PER = sorted((item.permission_id) for item in list(User.objects.filter(user_permissions__user=2)))

It is saying  'User' object has no attribute 'permission_id.

Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

`User.objects.filter(...)` gets queryset for users. Thus item is an `User()` instance. To access permission of the item, directly `item.user_permissions.all()`. Thus in your case

```
User(pk=2).user_permissions.values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('pk')
# or
[x.pk for x in Permission.objects.filter(user=2).order_by('pk')]
```

Refs [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) for more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Permission ids, you'd want to query the Permission table directly.

```
permission_ids = Permission.objects.filter(user=2).values_list('id', flat=True)
```